# Invalid object initializer issue in jquery get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, initializer

I want to code an html button with jQuery, when `chart` button is pressed, will take values from some text inputs, prepare a json of them and will perform a get request including the json with values.

```
$(".chart").click(function(){

    var args = {}

    args['fx'] = $("#tolerancia").val()
    args['a'] = $("#a").val()
    args['b'] = $("#b").val()
    args['tolerancia'] = $("#tolerancia").val()
    args['iteracionesMaximas'] = $("#iteracionesMaximas").val()

    $.get("/taylor",{args},function(resultado){
        console.log(resultado)
    })
})
```

I'm getting an *`Invalid object initializer`* message in console right on line of:

```
$.get("/taylor",{args},function(resultado){
```

What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$.get("/taylor", args, function(resultado) {
    console.log(resultado)
});
```

Note: `{args}` is invalid syntax. `args` is already an object, so you don't need to wrap it in any other brackets.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, how can I catch args at node side?

Comment: In Express you use `req.query`. In pure Node `url.parse`.